# Exploit google map's directions API on Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to display a direction on a map.
For now I use the Xamarin forms "Maps" module which is multiplateforme.
I also made a custom renderer to display additionnal informations on the map.

But the "Maps" module doesn't have access to the direction API of google map.

So what should I do ?

- Should I create an API key to get the directions from HTTP ?

or

- Should I use the google map implementation that I suppose is available in the Xamarin.android part of the project.

Comment: I guess the clean way is to make an ApiKey and get directions via Http. Using undocumented code in xamarin may or may not work but is likely to break in the future

Comment: If I use the HTTP method I can't put any security on my key. The only options are setting some range of authorized IPs, domain names or selecting "android App" (wich doesn't work if I use the http option. That's only for SDKs). So no security ?

Comment: Hm No, no security isn't a way to go. Have you considered building an Android aar project with any functionality you need and importing this to your xamarin project? Never worked with xamarin myself, but https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/ seems like a good entry point

Comment: I'll read about that. Thx

Comment: another idea (depending on your target build version) might be to request the API Key via a pinned certificate https request (ensure nobody taps in) and store it in the Security Chip which you get access to via AndroidKeystore https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Comment: yep indeed ! its a good idear ! It would limit the possibilities of getting the key.